# dynamic_cast working on related types casting is sucess

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    virtual void dummy() {};
    void f()
    {
        cout << endl << "A f()";
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        int i;
        cout << endl << "func() of B";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* ptr1;
    B* ptr2;
    ptr1 = new A;
    ptr2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr1);
    if (ptr2 == NULL)
        cout << endl << "dynamicastfailed";
    cout << endl << "Type=" << typeid(ptr2).name();
    ptr2->func();
}
```

`dynamic_cast` is successful. After casting the pointer from `A*` to `B*` and function can be invoked by using the pointer. My questions are:

1. How unrelated object pointer can be casted?
2. how the function call works for `ptr2` (pointer casted from `A*` to `b*`).

Comment: With this code, I got "dynamicastfailed".

Comment: `dynamic_cast < B * >(ptr1)` is UB, if I'm not mistaken, because `B` is not a polymorphic type (it has no virtual members). Actually I'm kind of surprised that it even compiles, since the types `A` and `B` are not related.

Comment: @cdhowie: I compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. The only warning I got was for the unused `int i;` in `B::func()`.

Comment: @cdhowie: You are mistaken, the important part is that `decltype(*ptr1)` is a derived class of `B`, or a polymorphic class. It's polymorphic.

Comment: The code is fine (besides the missing logic and `ptr2->func();`) and the dynamic_cast fails, as it should (@cdhowie the source is polymorphic)

Answer (score 0):

What you have going on here is undefined behavior. `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer when it can't convert the object to the target type. Since `A` and `B` are unrelated types, `dynamic_cast` does indeed return a null pointer.

Since you don't check the value of `ptr2` before you dereference it, all bets are off. You've dereferenced a null pointer, so your program may or may not work, or it can cause a crash. Anything can happen, but your program's behavior is not valid either way.

Comment: I am doing the NULL check for ptr2 ,It is not null.ok i agree that the call may be undefined behaviour

Comment: @user3227126 The message "dynamicast failed" did not show up for you? [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f7a38ba05df07fe).

Comment: @user3227126: You check it, but then dereference it anyway even if it is null.

Comment: @user3227126: UB is retroactive. [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply ,i got the point the mistake lies in null pointer check ,sorry .thanks a lot